# Magento inventory rest api returns 404 for some products

Tags: magento-1.8, api, rest-api, inventory

When I try to fetch inventory of a product using `/api/rest/stockitems/id` URL, I get a 404 error. But when I try to fetch the same product using `/api/rest/products/id` URL, it works just fine.

```
GET /api/rest/stockitems/3931    -> Not Found 404

GET /api/rest/products/3931      -> Found 200
```

This is happening with the products of `id` between `3807` to `3931`.

As an example: if I try to fetch inventory of product `3806` and all the products before it, it works just fine:

```
GET /api/rest/stockitems/3806    -> Found 200
```

I am running Magento version 1.8.1.

Why is this happening?

**UPDATE:**

I should've mentioned earlier that I want to update quantities of products on Magento, and `PUT` requests aren't working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes like `/stockitems/:id` or `/products/:id` point to the entities specified in the URL (stock item and product respectively).

If you want to get list of stock items related to the specific product, use `GET /api/rest/stockitems` with filter by `product_id` field. The following format should work:

`GET /api/rest/stockitems&filter[1][attribute]=product_id&filter[1][eq]=3807`

Update according to the question change: to update stock item, just iterate over received stock items (should be 1 item per product) and update quantity using

```
PUT /api/rest/stockitems/:stockItemId
{
   "qty": 123
   "is_in_stock": 1 //Should be 0 if qty is 0
}
```

Comment: I just don't want to get list of products, but I'd like to update quantities of products too. So, the `PUT` requests are not working either.

Comment: tl;dr for this answer is: product with ID 3931 can have ANY stock item ID. So, you need to find stock item ID for given product ID.

Comment: @AdvancedLogic Thanks, that *tl;dr* was really helpful.

Comment: @AlexPaliarush Thanks, your answer solved the problem! Will award bounty in 2 hours (general protocol).